# Trouble exporting object with simple mixed shader Blender -> Game Engine

Tags: texturing, materials, uv, shaders, export

Thanks in advance for your time, I spent 2 hours trying to figure this out.

I have a terrain. I simply want to paint 2 textures on it, sometimes they blend. So I made a material with three images inputs :

```
Ground 1 -> Mix Shader Shader 1
Ground 2 -> Mix Shader Shader 2
Blendmask B/W -> Mix Shader Factor
```

Everything's good, it works, looks ok for me. But when I want to export the project (gltf with separate data) only Ground 1 is exported along ! I tried to send my Mix Shader output to a Shader to RGB but then when I exported only the B/W Blendmask went along !

In Material Properties I SEE the image I'd love to export (red rect) but how can I get it ?

Thanks

[image]